# Grub is in unusable state since w10 update

Tags: windows-10, debian, multi-boot, grub

I am on a Vaio laptop with Debian Jessie / W10 dual boot and Grub 2.02~beta2-22+deb8u1. Since W10's latest update something weird happened to my grub-efi.

When I boot my computer I get this error message and prompt:

```
error: unknown filesystem.
grub rescue> set
cmdpath=(hd0,gpt3)/EFI/Boot
prefix=(hd0,gpt7)/boot/grub
root=hd0,gpt7
```

and the problem is clear to me. When I repoint `prefix` and `root` to `gpt8`, grub is able to start as usual. So now I want to make those changes permanent using `update-grub` and `grub-install /dev/sda`, but they do not work. I have alslo tried to reinstall grub with `apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi`. I really cannot see what the problem might be, so any help at this point is greatly appreciated..

---

Some command outputs:

$ sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C8BC1CE8-FD40-4DDA-96B5-D6163C4783D3

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    534527    532480   260M unknown
/dev/sda2     534528   3553279   3018752   1.5G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda3    3553280   4085759    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda4    4085760   4347903    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda5    4347904 300871478 296523575 141.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  300871680 302587903   1716224   838M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7  302587904 447993855 145405952  69.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda8  447995904 482609151  34613248  16.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda9  482609152 499195903  16586752   7.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda10 499195904 500117503    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
```

$ sudo parted -l

```
Model: ATA SAMSUNG MZHPU256 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  274MB   273MB   fat32           EFI system partition          hidden
 2      274MB   1819MB  1546MB  ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 3      1819MB  2092MB  273MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot, esp
 4      2092MB  2226MB  134MB                   Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 5      2226MB  154GB   152GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 6      154GB   155GB   879MB   ntfs                                          hidden, diag
 7      155GB   229GB   74.4GB  ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 8      229GB   247GB   17.7GB  ext4
 9      247GB   256GB   8492MB  linux-swap(v1)
10      256GB   256GB   472MB   ntfs                                          hidden, diag
```

$ sudo blkid

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="SONYSYS" UUID="362F-ED41" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="a0b5ecb9-f876-4cfc-8af2-af7d05fcab60"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Windows RE tools" UUID="5A7CA3A87CA37CFF" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="62da8ec6-3599-4532-85d7-380d53e29dd4"
/dev/sda3: UUID="885F-1C6A" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="b6bb7dd4-236e-435f-b341-bdf2ffe6081d"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="System" UUID="90FA595CFA594020" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="07cdd53b-236f-440b-bb4b-972d6d37fb38"
/dev/sda6: UUID="00B8845EB8845456" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="94ad7c1c-66c7-4213-9a50-2e26579ce698"
/dev/sda7: LABEL="Shared" UUID="7A8C03FC8C03B1A5" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="67a5a372-ae1a-4a87-85f4-50e61cc298dc"
/dev/sda8: UUID="89128915-6da6-4e9e-a6e5-6982361d14ca" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="35a2f565-5105-4608-81a7-160d58ad1a71"
/dev/sda9: UUID="16135ad5-d9c2-4f74-a630-be40dfd6af59" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="a5bc56ed-66c3-462d-86b5-429a1f9ed2d9"
/dev/sda10: UUID="1C66A14A66A1260C" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="e375bed8-a332-4b1e-9d7b-732b34190193"
/dev/sda4: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="a71544c6-1fae-4808-b8a1-c0498c689d66"
```

$ sudo update-grub

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background: /home/johan/img/375578.png
Found background image: /home/johan/img/375578.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda3@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

$ sudo cat /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
#
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
# /dev/sda8 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=89128915-6da6-4e9e-a6e5-6982361d14ca /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
#
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=362F-ED41  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# UUID=885F-1C6A  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
#
# swap was on /dev/sda8 during installation
# /dev/sda9 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=16135ad5-d9c2-4f74-a630-be40dfd6af59 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

$df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda8        17G   11G  4.7G  70% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  8.8M  1.6G   1% /run
tmpfs           3.9G   68K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       256M   21M  236M   8% /boot/efi
tmpfs           792M  8.0K  792M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Ty for your help o.O <3

Comment: Have you tried editing `grub.cfg`?

Comment: It is my understanding that /boot/grub/grub.cfg should not directly be edited, though I have been trying to do that as well. It is not very clear to me where I would start editing this file, though. Somehow I need to reconfigure grub _before_ it loads all the info from the partition